# How to restrict a JSP hit counter?

Tags: java, jsp, hitcounter

I am writing a hit counter in JSP, for my coursework. I have write the code, and there is not error and its working, but the problem is that:
if the user have open the website and try to use different page, whenever that the user goes back to the home page the counter still is adding a number, how can I restrict this part? shall restrict it with session?
this is my code :

```
<jsp:useBean id="counter" scope="application" class="counter.CounterBean" />
The current count for the counter bean is:
<jsp:setProperty name="counter" property="coun" value="1"></jsp:setProperty>
<%
counter.saveCount();
int _numberofvisitors=counter.getVisitorsNumber();
out.println(_numberofvisitors);
%>
```

Bean:

```
package counter;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CounterBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    int coun = 0;

    public CounterBean() {
        database.DatabaseManager.getInstance().getDatabaseConnection();
    }

    public int getCoun() {
        return this.coun;
    }

    public void setCoun(int coun) {
        this.coun += coun;
    }

    public boolean saveCount() {
        boolean _save = false;
        database.SQLUpdateStatement sqlupdate = new database.SQLUpdateStatement("counter", "hitcounter");
        sqlupdate.addColumn("hitcounter", getCoun());
        if (sqlupdate.Execute()) {
            _save = true;
        }
        return _save;
    }

    public int getVisitorsNumber() throws SQLException {
        int numberOfVisitors = 0;
        if (database.DatabaseManager.getInstance().connectionOK()) {
            database.SQLSelectStatement sqlselect = new database.SQLSelectStatement("counter", "hitcounter", "0");
            ResultSet _userExist = sqlselect.executeWithNoCondition();
            if (_userExist.next()) {
                numberOfVisitors = _userExist.getInt("hitcounter");                
            }
        }
        return numberOfVisitors;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you'd like to count: 1 unique visitor everytime regardless of the visited pages? Do you want to count this based on sessions or on unique IP's? Or do you want to count unique pageviews per visitor everytime? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this part of the code:

```
<%
counter.saveCount();
int _numberofvisitors=counter.getVisitorsNumber();
out.println(_numberofvisitors);
%>
```

To

```
<%
if (session.isNew()) {
    counter.saveCount();
} else {
    counter.setCoun(-1);
}
int _numberofvisitors=counter.getVisitorsNumber();
out.println(_numberofvisitors);
%>
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** By the way, it's better to choose better names for the methods of your Counter class. First of all, change `setCoun` to `setCount`. Besides, a setter method usually just assigns the value passed to it to its associated field. If you want to increment the value of `coun`, change the method name to `addCount`. Then increment the `count` value like:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="counter" property="coun" value="${1 + counter.coun}"></jsp:setProperty>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Applcation object in JSP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <%


Integer hitsCount=(Integer)application.getAttribute("hitcount");
int m;
       if(hitsCount==null)
   {

            m=1;

      hitsCount =Integer.valueOf(m);
                   application.setAttribute("hitcount", hitsCount);
 }
 else
     {

      hitsCount=(Integer)application.getAttribute("hitcount");
       m=hitsCount.intValue()+1;
      hitsCount=   Integer.valueOf(m);
        application.setAttribute("hitcount", hitsCount);

     }



%>


<center>
<p>Total number of visits:<%=hitsCount.intValue()%> </p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```